# Cannot Parse Date from Twitter

Tags: java, date, twitter

I´m getting a list of twitter dates via the search API of twitter.

```
String dateString = ((JSONObject)ar.get(i)).get("created_at").toString();
// Ej: "Tue May 12 19:58:26 +0000 2015"
String TWITTER="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER);
Date d = sf.parse(dateString);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(d) );
```

Can anyone help me see what I´m doing wrong?

I don´t see any errors in my date format. However, I´m getting an unparseable date Exception on the `sf.parse(dateString);` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is Locale dependent, so just use an explicit english Locale:

```
 String TWITTER="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy";
 SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER,Locale.ENGLISH);
```